# Python でリストをカンマ区切りで出力したい

Tags: python, python3

リストの内容をカンマ区切りでテキストに出力するには
どの様にすればよいのでしょうか？

`["犬", "ネコ", "豚"]` というリストを以下の様にテキストに書き込みたいです。

```
犬,ネコ,豚
```

下記コードを実行すると

```py
str_li = ["犬", "ネコ", "豚"]

with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for x in str_li:
        f.write(x)
```

実行結果（test.txt）

```
犬ネコ豚
```

```py
with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for x in str_li:
        new_x = ",".join(x) # joinで連結
        f.write(new_x)
```

以下の様になってしまいます。

```
犬ネ,コ豚
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

念のため，数値リストの場合も加えました。

```
str_li = ['犬', 'ネコ', '豚']
num_li = [1, 2, 3]

with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(','.join(str_li) + '\n')
    f.write(','.join([str(x) for x in num_li]) + '\n')

with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print(f.read(), end='')
```

```
犬,ネコ,豚
1,2,3
```

（追記）
内包表記を使わない記述は下記になります。

```
num_li = [1, 2, 3]

num2str_li = []
for x in num_li:
    num2str_li.append(str(x))

with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(','.join(num2str_li) + '\n')
```

Comment: num_li = [1, 2, 3]
with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='shift-jis') as f:
    for x in num_li:
        f.write(",".join(str(x)))
内包表記が、まだあまりわかっていないので、上記の様にしてみましたがテキスト内には、123 と書き込まれてしまいます。

Comment: @sinshin [数値をカンマ区切りでテキスト出力する方法について](https://teratail.com/questions/iz9b7fbeciinww#reply-oktzfar5ucjr2i) で解決済みなのではありませんか？

Answer (score 4):

joinは結合後の文字列を返すので、forでリストの中身を取り出さなくてもよいです。

```
str_li = ["犬", "ネコ", "豚"]

f = open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
f.write(",".join(str_li))
f.close()
```

withを使ってファイルの閉じ忘れをなくしたい場合は、

```
with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(",".join(str_li))
```

となります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
リストが数値の場合は、以下の様にしてよろしいのでしょうか？一度、srt()で文字列へ変換しておりますが、出力結果は、123になってしまいます。

li = [1, 2, 3]
with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='shift-jis') as f:
    for x in li:
        f.write(",".join(str(x)))

Comment: @KiYugadgeter 質問者さんは最初からwithを使っています。その説明は不要ですよね。
それよりもコメントであるように、joinの引数にstringを指定してしまった場合の説明が必要です。

Answer (score 2):

ループで処理する必要は恐らくなくて、事前に連結した文字列を作成してそのまま書きこめば良さそうです。

**例:**

```py
str_li = ["犬", "ネコ", "豚"]
new_x = ",".join(str_li)

with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(new_x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
str_li = ["犬", "ネコ", "豚"]

with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print(*str_li, sep=',', file=f)
```

**実行結果**

```bash
$ cat test.txt
犬,ネコ,豚
```

Comment: 環境は明示されていません。catが使えると思うのは良くないです。

Comment: @dameo さん、スタック・オーバーフローでは質問に対して部分的な回答をすることは特に禁止されていません。また、もし更に一般的で役立つ回答がある場合は是非ご自身でご投稿なさってみてください。

Comment: @nekketsuuu
catが何か知らない人が見たら混乱するだけなので、環境未指定ならそれくらいの配慮をして当然だと思いますけどね。親切で指摘してるだけですよ。